# Forcing Dropdown Menu to close when I click to another dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, webflow

This is the website I am working on and I need help only in MOBILE view, so before starting taking a look to it, make sure you opened it on phone: https://elektronskasrbija.webflow.io/

In the menu, there is a dropdown with so much other dropdowns below it (client's will).
Currently, you are able to open as many Sub Dropdowns as you wish. My goal is to make one Sub Dropdown to close when the user clicks to another Sub Dropdown (as a refference, you can check a desktop version of the same website to see how it should work like).

Note: I didn't use Native Webflow dropdown, my dropdowns are custom made with divs (on destkop I did use native dropdowns so there works perfectly - don't ask why I didn't use :)). Also, if you write the code, for a help, the class of Sub Dropdown trigger is: .project-sub-dropdown-trigger

I simply don't know how to do this so I haven't tried.